# How to configure Zeitwerk to work with acronym inflections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines, zeitwerk

My Rails app is using an engine that defines an acronym inflection:

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym "UI"
end
```

This means (for example) that Rails will load `UIHelper` from `helpers/ui_helper.rb` rather than `UiHelper`.

Now I want to user a gem ([`"motor-admin"`](https://github.com/motor-admin/motor-admin-rails)) but I'm getting this error:

```
uninitialized constant Motor::UIController
```

This is because the gem's class name is `Motor::UiController` but the inflections are looking for `Motor::UIController` (note the `Ui` vs `UI`).

I've tried following the [Customizing Inflections](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#customizing-inflections) in the Rails Guides, but can't seem to make the error go away.

How can I configure Rails to correctly load `Motor::UiController` with the `"UI"` acronym inflection?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```rb
Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector.inflect(
    'ui_controller' => 'UIController'
  )
end
```

edit to add: you might have to do this for the models as well. If you run `bin/rails zeitwerk:check` it will tell you the files that still need to be changed.

I haven't tried to inflect an included gems controller names, but I did do an upgrade from 5.2 to 7.0 and had to do this for my own controller names which were in the same form that Motor seems to be taking.